# implementing python set logic (as in get and set)

Tags: python

So I have a class,

```
import numpy as np
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
       self.means = np.zeros(5)
```

And I have functions that expect an `ndarray` object...yet I have function calls I need to integrate my code with that set my object's mean to a list.  Once that happens, everything breaks.

I need a way to force the class to set the incoming list as an ndarray. It seems like this is possible, reviewing the `__set__ and __setattrib__` in the python documentation...but after reading the documentation, I am still mystified as to how to get the desired behavior.

What I want is to ensure that when other code says,

```
MyClass.means = [0,0,0,0]
```

the means get set to: `np.array([0,0,0,0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a property setter:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._means = np.zeros(5)

    @property
    def means(self):
        return self._means  # Note the underscore

    @means.setter
    def means(self, value):
        # Convert to np array before setting
        self._means = np.array(value)
```